# Parametric mixin values (not) affecting a nested variable

Tags: css, grid, sass, mixins

I'm trying to allow for instances where an element in a column is the only or first item on a line (giving it the appropriate margins) with the added classes of .first, .only, and .firstOnly. Is there a way to incorporate the values supplied in a parametric mixin to define (or change) a variable?

```
$colCount: 2;
$colSpan: 1;
$gutter: 4%;

$width: $colSpan * ((100% - $gutter) / $colCount);


@mixin width($colCount: 2, $colSpan: 1, $gutter: 4%) {
    $width: $colSpan * ((100% - $gutter) / $colCount);
}

@mixin columns($colCount: 2, $colSpan: 1, $gutter: 4%) { 
    @content;
    @include width() {
        width: $width;
    }


    &.first {
        @include first();
    }

    &.only {
        @include only();
    }

    &.firstOnly {
        @include firstOnly();
    }
}

@mixin first($colCount: 2, $colSpan: 1, $gutter: 4%) {
    margin-left: 100% - $width;
}

@mixin only($colCount: 2, $colSpan: 1, $gutter: 4%) {
    margin-left: 100% - (2 * $width) - (2 * $gutter);
}

@mixin firstOnly($colCount: 2, $colSpan: 1, $gutter: 4%) {
    margin-left: 100% - $width - $gutter;
    margin-right: 100% - $width;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, if you plan on using Compass in the future, you're going to have naming conflicts.  Columns is the name of the mixin for vendor prefixed CSS columns (see http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/columns/#mixin-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of things going on here that aren't quite right.

```
// If this is part of a reusable library, use the default flag
// I typically prefer prefixing global variables to avoid collisions with other code
// (eg. $grid-colCount instead of $colCount)
$colCount: 2 !default;
$colSpan: 1 !default;
$gutter: 4% !default;

// Mixin changed to a function, better for its intended purpose
@function width($colCount: $colCount, $colSpan: $colSpan, $gutter: $gutter) {
    @return $colSpan * ((100% - $gutter) / $colCount);
}

// The arguments are set to our global variables by default
@mixin columns($colCount: $colCount, $colSpan: $colSpan, $gutter: $gutter) { 
    @content;
    // Something weird was going on here that just plain didn't compile
    width: width($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter);

    &.first {
        // This is where your mixin was getting messed up,
        // it wasn't passing the values it received on to the mixins
        @include first($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter);
    }

    &.only {
        @include only($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter);
    }

    &.firstOnly {
        @include firstOnly($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter);
    }
}

@mixin first($colCount: $colCount, $colSpan: $colSpan, $gutter: $gutter) {
    margin-left: 100% - width($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter);
}

@mixin only($colCount: $colCount, $colSpan: $colSpan, $gutter: $gutter) {
    margin-left: 100% - (2 * width($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter)) - (2 * $gutter);
}

@mixin firstOnly($colCount: $colCount, $colSpan: $colSpan, $gutter: $gutter) {
    margin-left: 100% - width($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter) - $gutter;
    margin-right: 100% - width($colCount, $colSpan, $gutter);
}
```

When we call the mixins like this:

```
.test {
    @include columns(3, 8, 40%);
}

.test2 {
    @include columns;
}
```

We get this result:

```
.test {
  width: 160%;
}

.test.first {
  margin-left: -60%;
}

.test.only {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

.test.firstOnly {
  margin-left: -100%;
  margin-right: -60%;
}


.test2 {
  width: 48%;
}

.test2.first {
  margin-left: 52%;
}

.test2.only {
  margin-left: -4%;
}

.test2.firstOnly {
  margin-left: 48%;
  margin-right: 52%;
}
```